# Foreach with a Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a way to echo my values in PHP.

I've this array:

```
$arr = array(
    'Golfs' => array('table' => 'Golfs', 'IntExt' => 'extern', 'SummerWinter' => 'summer'),
    'Beaches' => array('table' => 'Beaches', 'IntExt' => 'extern', 'SummerWinter' => 'summer'),
    'MunicipalRegionalParks' => array('table' => 'MunicipalRegionalParks', 'IntExt' => 'extern', 'SummerWinter' => 'summer'),
    'ThemeParks' => array('table' => 'ThemeParks', 'IntExt' => 'extern', 'SummerWinter' => 'summer'),
    'Caves' => array('table' => 'Caves', 'IntExt' => 'intern extern', 'SummerWinter' => 'summer')
);
```

I want to echo for each one :

- The table name
- The IntExt value
- The SummerWinter value

I tried:

```
foreach($arr['table'] as $result) {
    echo $result['IntExt'], '<br>';
}
```

But:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `$arr['table']` as argument for `foreach`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['IntExt'].'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr as $set){
  foreach($set as $data){
    echo $data . "<br/>" ;
  }

  echo "<br/>" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
foreach($arr as $key => $result) {
    echo "<strong>" . $key . "</strong><br>";
    echo "table name : " . $result['table'] . "<br>";
    echo " IntExt : " . $result['IntExt'] . "<br>";
    echo "SummerWinter : " . $result['SummerWinter'] . "<br>";
    echo "--------------------------------------------------<br><br>";
}
```

**output**

```
Golfs
table name : Golfs
IntExt : extern
SummerWinter : summer
--------------------------------------------------

Beaches
table name : Beaches
IntExt : extern
SummerWinter : summer
--------------------------------------------------

MunicipalRegionalParks
table name : MunicipalRegionalParks
IntExt : extern
SummerWinter : summer
--------------------------------------------------

ThemeParks
table name : ThemeParks
IntExt : extern
SummerWinter : summer
--------------------------------------------------

Caves
table name : Caves
IntExt : intern extern
SummerWinter : summer
--------------------------------------------------
```